# How to set the VrCamera in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm making an RPG game, the only difficulty I've reached is the camera; I don't know how to set that.

I've tried that code:

```
if (Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.rotation.EulerAngles.y, Rotator) > 7)
{
    float x = Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.rotation.EulerAngles.y, Rotator);
    Container.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * -x);
    Rotator = transform.rotation.EulerAngles.y;
}
else
{
    if (Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.rotation.EulerAngles.y, Rotator) < -7)
    {
        float x = Mathf.DeltaAngle(transform.rotation.EulerAngles.y, Rotator);
        Container.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * -x);

        Rotator = transform.rotation.EulerAngles.y;
    }
}
```

and if I lower my head the character moves in front of me, when I raise my head back to normal.

How to set a VR camera for an RPG game?

Comment: which vr set your are targeting?

Comment: the computer vr